# MockMVC @PathVariable not work when using String

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, mockito, mockmvc

Mockmvc test not work when Pathvariable is a String but work on int.
Here is my code:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/etablissement/{typeEtablissement}")
public class EtablissementController{
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String accueil(@PathVariable("typeEtablissement") String typeEtablissement) {
        return "/test";
    }
}

// somewhere in my test
mockMvc.perform(get("/etablissement/{typeEtablissement}", "test")).andExpect(status().isOk()); // Error 400
```

But, if I use int instead of String it works

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String accueil(@PathVariable("typeEtablissement") int typeEtablissement) {
    return "/test";
}

// somewhere in my test
mockMvc.perform(get("/etablissement/{typeEtablissement}", 123)).andExpect(status().isOk()); // Works
```

Using Object also work

```
public String accueil(@PathVariable("typeEtablissement") Object typeEtablissement) {}
```

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of a GetMapping who should help you :

```
@GetMapping("/{typeEtablissement}/{something2}/{something3}")
    public List<Object> extract(
            @PathVariable String typeEtablissement,
            @PathVariable String something2,
            @PathVariable String something3) {

List<Object> object = objectService.extractDatas(typeEtablissement, something2, something3);

return object;
}
```

Comment: Nope, still not work. I've already tried that

Answer (score 0):

Strange cause it means typeEtablissement is an int. You can also create a new variable after with valueOf:

```
@GetMapping("/{typeEtablissement}/{something2}/{something3}")
    public List<Object> extract(
            @PathVariable String typeEtablissement,
            @PathVariable String something2,
            @PathVariable String something3) {

String typeEtablissementConverted = String.valueOf(typeEtablissement );

List<Object> object = objectService.extractDatas(typeEtablissementConverted, something2, something3);

return object;
}
```

Comment: No it will be a string. I've just notice that it only not work when I use @PathVariable String.
Also, app work fine for now, it's just the Spring MockMVC for my web layer test that is not work. Very strange as you said